# PHP Send an Email using mail function

Tags: php

I am trying to send an email using [php](/questions/tagged/php) but unable to do it, whereas I am getting data into `MySQL` database.

I have posted my whole code, please check and let me know where's the mistake.

```
$objConnect = mysql_connect("localhost","username","pwd");
$objDB = mysql_select_db("database");

$strName = $_POST["name"];
$strEmail = $_POST["email"];

$to      = $strEmail;
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: mymail@gmail.com' . "\r\n" .
'Reply-To: mymail@gmail.com' . "\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

$strSQL = "insert into data (name, email) VALUES ('".$strName."','".$strEmail."')";
$objQuery = mysql_query($strSQL);

if(!$objQuery)
    {
        $arr['StatusID'] = "0"; 
        $arr['Message'] = "Cannot save data!";  
    }
    else
    {
        mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
        $arr['StatusID'] = "1"; 
        $arr['Message'] = "Data saved successfully";    
    }

    mysql_close($objConnect);

    echo json_encode($arr);
```

Comment: Do `var_dump(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers))` and see what it is returning.

Comment: are you doing the test locally?

Comment: @Sougata getting Unable to upload

Comment: I am testing it on live server @jameshwartlopez

Comment: @Sun I think its worth checking if you have a php error and also check if your else code that contains your mail code has really been executed.

Comment: Your primary mistake is calling `mail` yourself, and thus making yourself responsible for a very large amount of work to format your messages correctly and protect yourself from attack (which you're currently not doing at all). Don't do it; use a library like [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) that you tagged this question with, and base your code on one of the examples provided. Meanwhile, read your mail server's log, usually in `/var/log/mail.log`.

Answer (score 0):

This code is really working ...

```
<?php
    $to      = 'to_email@gmail.com';
    $subject = 'the subject';
    $message = 'hello';
    $headers = 'From: mymail@gmail.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: mymail@gmail.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
    $errLevel = error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);  // suppress NOTICEs
    if(!mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)){
        error_reporting($errLevel);
    }
?>
```

Comment: Can you please explain what mistake OP did and how your code help to solve it? Just code is not enough.

Answer (score 0):

You have not added `mail()` function in your code then how will it send the mail and to send email from `localhost` it should be properly configured. Below code will work on the server.

```
$objConnect = mysql_connect("localhost","username","pwd");
$objDB = mysql_select_db("database");
$strName = $_POST["name"];
$strEmail = $_POST["email"];
$to      = $strEmail;
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: mymail@gmail.com' . "\r\n" .
           'Reply-To: mymail@gmail.com' . "\r\n" .
           'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
if(!mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)){
  echo 'Mail cant be send';
}
else
{
$strSQL = "insert into data (name, email) VALUES ('".$strName."','".$strEmail."')";
$objQuery = mysql_query($strSQL);
if(!$objQuery)
   {
    $arr['StatusID'] = "0"; 
    $arr['Message'] = "Cannot save data!";  
}
else
{
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    $arr['StatusID'] = "1"; 
    $arr['Message'] = "Data saved successfully";    
}
echo json_encode($arr);
  }
   mysql_close($objConnect);
```

Comment: I have tried your way yet not done

Comment: you are doing it from the server or from the local host? first check if the mail server is properly working by simply sending one test mail.

Comment: @Sun first simply check the mail server working or not

Comment: The OP's code already calls `mail`.